# how to show some text in html.LabelFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I am doing int like this:

```
Hello <%=  Html.LabelFor(user => user.UserName)%>
```

But iam getting not a value which is in Property but something strange like this:

```
Hello User Name,
```

How can do it to give some value in label out?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason for this is because `Html.LabelFor` will do just that - create a label for the property. In this case, it is producing a label of 'User Name' since the property name is UserName.

You just need to look at the model (or whatever your passing to the view) to return the property value: `Html.Encode(Model.UserName)`

*Update (since this was nearly 3 years ago but people have recently upvoted):*

You can just use `<%: Model.UserName %>` to get the HTML encoded value (`<%=` writes it as raw and `<%:` writes it encoded).

If you're using a Razor view engine, then `@Model.Username` will write it out already encoded.

Answer (score 13):

Add DataAnnotations to your model/viewmodel:

```
public class Customer
{
    [Display(Name = "Email Address", Description = "An email address is needed to provide notifications about the order.")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType=typeof(DisplayResources), Name="LName", Description="LNameDescription")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute(v=VS.95).aspx

If you don't provide a display name by the `DisplayAttribute` then `Html.EditorFor(...)` uses the properties name, spliting it on upper case letters:

**PropertyName --> Label text**
Email --> Email
EmailAdress --> Email Address